# How to convert http:namenode-ip:50070/conf XML response into JSON type?

Tags: java, json, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I want to fetch the hadoop cluster config parameters from REST response. But the ***http:namenode-ip:50070/conf*** giving me the XML type response but i want these config details in JSON format how can get the same in java code?
Any idea how can get the JSON response instead of XML? or how can covert it into JSON type in java code without using any external library?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the data default in JSON,you can provide some properties to your controller like

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

or you can use:

```
 @JSONRequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: I'm trying to fetch data in simple java application(not using spring/ annotation) without any external library. Can we do this without including the external library?